# How do I replicate from a secured CouchDB database?

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon

I am using Fauxton in a test environment to replicate from our test server to my local server. I logged in to the test server in another browser tab, but replication still fails despite the cookie being there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to prepend your username and your password to the remote replication URI:

```
https://user:password@testcouchdb.mycompany.com:7984/mydb
```

See http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#Authentication for more information.

(This approach should be reviewed or avoided in a production environment.)